# Sending a JMS message to a remote queue on JBoss AS 5 and AS 7

Tags: jms, jboss5.x, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have two servers

1. JBoss as 5.1 with an application sending JMS messages
2. JBoss AS 7 server with the queue implemented and an MDB consuming messages

I would like to send a message from server one to server two. I would like the message to be consumed on server two.

I think JBoss AS 7 uses HornetQ.

Any hints on how to send a message to a remote queue? I'm more interested on how to send messages because it is on the remote server, and I think the consuming part should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that JBoss AS 7 uses HornetQ for messaging as the JMS provider. A great resource is the JBoss community documentation for [HornetQ](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html). There is also an excellent post on the JBoss community forums about [setting up HornetQ](https://community.jboss.org/message/721977#721977#721977) across two instances of AS 7.

You will need to define your connectors and acceptors that make up the transports, which in your case will include [netty](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#configuring-transports) as your client and server are running in different JVMs (otherwise you could use invm). Creating your connection factories will differ on each JBoss AS instance (for example, there is no Management CLI on JBoss AS 5), but the above link will give you a good reference, and you can ask targeted questions in there.